# Convert the date from Milliseconds format to normal format in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, milliseconds

I am getting the date from database  in Milliseconds format.I am convrting that date in to the normal date format.But it returns wrong date.Once please give me the solution in ios

The date in milliseconds is 1385856000000

After convert that date i am getting 10/26/1970.

But real date is 12/1/2013 .

I am using the following code is

```
int dobint = [secondChangeDob intValue];

            NSTimeInterval timeInSecond = dobint/1000;

            NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInSecond];

            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
            NSString *formattedDate=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
            NSLog(@"Formatted Date : %@",formattedDate);
            NSUserDefaults *dateDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [dateDef setObject:formattedDate forKey:@"bDATE"];
```

---

Comment: I suggest get date from database as `NSDate`.

Answer (score 6):

Your **secondChangeDob** as an **int** won't work with such a value, as an **int** is simply too small to hold the value you are storing in an **NSNumber**.

**NSTimeInterval** is of type **double** so you could try -

```
NSTimeInterval timeInSecond = [secondChangeDob doubleValue]/1000.0;
```

**NSNumber** has a method that will return a **double** named **doubleValue**. The above code returns **secondChangeDob** as a **double** so as no type casting issues arise when storing the result as an **NSTimeInterval**.

Answer (score 2):

the int is too small to hold 1385856000000

so the number gets corrupted

use e.g. an unsigned long long or just double

Comment: I'd suggest replacing it with NSInteger.

Comment: also don't forget to replace the call to intValue.

Comment: i'd use unsigned as it is an unsigned value

Comment: An unsigned long gives a warning, it actually should be a long long

Comment: Speaking about integer types, int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long are all the same size - 4 bytes on 32-bit iOS devices. It’s only on 64-bit devices where int and long differ. So to fit the value on both architectures, one of “long long” types or double should be used.

Comment: NSUInteger is unsigned int on 32-bit, so it is 4 bytes there. And unsigned long on 64 bit, so it is 8 bytes there.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this :

> NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1385856000000];

and

> NSDate *myDate = [NSDate
>   dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:1385856000000];

and

> NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1385856000000];

Comment: not an answer and not helpful ;)